# get merged branch name in azure pipelines yaml

Tags: azure-devops, bitbucket

When merging in a feature branch to the dev branch I want to get the merged branch name in my azure-pipeline.yaml on the build that gets triggered for the dev branch.

Is this possible?

Or when a branch gets deleted in my repo can I kick off a build that containers the delete branch name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BitBucket repo, it provides **default commit message** when trying to merge `feature1` into `dev` branch:

```
Merged in feature1 (pull request #{PullRequestNumber})
```

We can access this message via predefined variable `$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)`. And we can use [Powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) to output the Merged Branch Name, we can even use PS task to set variables in scripts so that following steps can also access this value. Here's my working script:

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $SourceVersionMessage = "$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)"
      $SourceBranchName = $SourceVersionMessage.split(" ")[2]

      #Output the Merged Branch Name
      Write-Host $SourceBranchName

      #Set the  `MergedBranchName` variable so that following steps can access the Merged Branch Name
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MergedBranchName]$SourceBranchName"
      
- script: |
    echo $(MergedBranchName)
```

The following step can access this value successfully:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I follow correctly, you're completing a Pull Request that merges a feature branch (source branch) into the develop branch (target branch) and this triggers a build on the develop branch. In the resulting build, you want to get the name of the feature branch? Maybe the feature branch followed a naming convention that is significant that you want to carry forward.

You do have the commit id available to you in the `$(Build.SourceVersion)` variable, so you should be able to fetch the commit information using the BitBucket REST API. This [commit details endpoint](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/commit/%7Bcommit%7D/pullrequests) can identify the pull-requests for a commit so you should be able to get the source branch information from there.

```
/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/commit/{commit}/pullrequests
```

You should also be able to fetch the commit message using $(Build.SourceVersionMessage)

Regarding triggering a build when a branch is deleted, there aren't any native triggers in the YAML syntax for this but you can define a trigger that uses a [webhook trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-webhooks). BitBucket does not seem to expose an event for when branches are deleted.

Comment: Looks like System.PullRequest is empty coming from BitBucket.  How would I just grab the commit name?  I could parse what i need to out of that

Comment: System.PullRequest is likely only valid for Azure Repos branch policy builds. Is Build.SourceVersion populated?

Comment: I removed the references to the PullRequest variables as these would only be available for Azure Repos. I also added a reference to SourceVersionMessage — these pieces of information should be available to your pipeline

Comment: I went down the path of using  $(Build.SourceVersionMessage) earlier, looks like I have to figure out how to parse that is for merged commit messages it throws an error: ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '255'.